# Communication between two partial views in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two partial view on parent views. First partial views is of questions where user will have a question listing with checkbox against each question.

Another partial view is for selected question which was selected from above partial view.Which shows selected question from above view.

Is there any way both can communicate like this? Any example will be highly appreciated. This both partial view be used at many places.

Comment: If there is one form in a view then your partial view will post values in the parent action.
Rough scenario : main view have form and 2 partial view will be rendered within this form.
Give it a shot, if it doesn't sorts your issue go for JQUERY

Comment: Main view is having one form and I am rendering two partial views in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you'd be able to do that was by using jQuery on the parent view to react to the change events when you're actually selecting questions.

Something like:

```
$("#selectQuestion").change(function () {
    //show data in other view for $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: This is not parent view. Partial view

Comment: Add the jQuery to the parent view. That's the only way to do it.